# How to disable an active item after dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I would like to create notifications that expire after a set amount of seconds.

I have created a property which is 'active' and when toggled to false it will hide.

Ideally, it would be nice to have the expiry automatically set in the slice, i.e. run the *disable* reducer within the runtime of the *notify* reducer but i'm not sure this is good practice, and am not sure how to pull it off.

What is the best way to pull this off? I was thinking of adding an expiry date on each item but since the 'active' field is already there I would like to set a timeout and toggle it to false after 3 seconds..

**Notification component:**

```
export function Notification() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    function disableAlert(id: number) {
        dispatch(disable({'id' : id}));
    }

    const notification_list = useSelector(getNotification);
    if (notification_list && notification_list.length > 0) {
        return notification_list.map((notification: any, index: number) =>
                notification.active ?
                    <Alert onClose={() => disableAlert(index)} style={{bottom: 50 * index}} severity={notification.mode}>{notification.message}</Alert> :
                    console.log(notification)
        )
    }

    return <></>
}
```

**Currently I have these slices:**

```
const disableMessage = (state: any, message_id: number) => {
    return state.messages.map((message:any) => message.id === message_id ?
        {...message, active: !message.active} :
        message
    );
}

export const notificationSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'notification',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        notify: (state, action) => {
            const { message, mode, active } = action.payload;
            state.messages.push({id: state.messages.length , message : message, mode: mode, active: active});
        },
        disable: (state, action) => {
            const { id } = action.payload;
            state.messages = disableMessage(state, id);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convention that reducers never contain any type of logic. I recommend to stick with this.

This leaves either the action or the Notification component. For me it makes more sense to tie the disable to the rendering of the individual notification so I would start the timeout there.

Ideally, you can split your `<Alert/>` component into the presentation and logic. Something similar to:

```js
const NotificationAlert = ({ disableAlert, id }) => {
  const notification = useSelector((state) => selectNotificationById(state, id));

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    disableAlert(id);
  }, [disableAlert, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => disableAlert(id), 3000);
  }, [disableAlert]);

  return (
    <Alert
      onClose={handleClick}
      style={{bottom: 50 * id}}
      severity={notification.mode}>{notification.message}</Alert> 
};
```

And

```js
export function Notification() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // memoize handler with useCallback
    const disableAlert = useCallback((id: number) => {
        dispatch(disable({'id' : id}));
    }, [dispatch]);

    // Filter for active notifications already in your selector
    const notificationIds = useSelector(getActiveNotificationIds);

    return notificationIds.map((id) =>
        <NotificationAlert disableAlert={disableAlert} id={id} />
    );
}
```

Also, make sure your `disableAlert` action is setting `active` to false rather than toggling it!

Comment: That will work. I recommand to add `clearTimeout` in the cleanup function of the effect, like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293864/react-settimeout-memory-leak

Comment: I recommend against adding a clear timeout. He wants to disable the item in any case - even if it unmounts early. Since the timeout doesn't even mutate state there is no reason to cancel it.